# How do i install wordpress in plesk panel 9.5.5

Tags: wordpress, installation, plesk

Am new to plesk panel.   Is this possible to install wordpress on plesk panel.hope someone can help for this issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [webapps.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Extract of this topic](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?86103-wordpress-installation-guide-on-plesk) :

1. Created a domain/subdomain in Plesk
2. Created a DB and username on Plesk
3. Copied all the files from unzipped "Wordpress" folder to /var/www/vhots/mydomain/httpdocs

   wget http://wordpress.org/latest.zip
4. Changed the wp-config.php with DB name, Username and password

Comment: hi bastien. is it possible to create a new domain while another exists

Comment: yes, you have this possibility same subdomain.

Comment: You can select my answer ? please